# I've an exception when run android application?

Tags: android

I think the error is from this manifest file ?!! when i want to start this activity "SearchResultForm" i have the exception ??

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ayanoo.forms"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/search" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="standard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="PersonDataForm" android:label="@layout/person_data_form"></activity>
    <activity android:name="SearchResultForm" android:theme="@style/CodeFont"></activity>
    <activity android:name="SendMessageForm" android:theme="@style/CodeFont"></activity>


</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please, fix the question as it has only the end of your manifest file. Also, please list a stacktrace.

Comment: So...how can we help without the error trace and relevant code (mentioned in the trace)?

Comment: The exception is the application ... is stopped unexpectedly , please try again later

Comment: Please learn to obtain stack traces: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have every activity of your appliaction listed within manifest file, like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ok" android:label="Application name">
        <activity android:name=".main_screen.MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: The exception is the application ... is stopped unexpectedly , please try again later

Comment: Please, look at the android logcat for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest has wrong links to your Activities (except the MainActivity).

You have:

```
<activity android:name="SearchResultForm" android:theme="@style/CodeFont"></activity>
```

Try to use:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchResultForm" android:theme="@style/CodeFont"></activity>
```

Pay attention to the dot.